# Cannot set Word Style's Base Style From C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, styles, interop

> Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word version 14.0.0.0.  .NET 4.0  VS 2010.

The MS Word API's Style class has a BaseStyle property that can be used to set the style's base (based on) style.  That property works fine for me in VBA.

However from C# using Word interopt there is no BaseStyle property.  However, there are two (undocumented as far as I can tell) functions set_BaseStyle() and get_BaseStyle().

When I call set_BaseStyle() I get a COMException with the message:

> "This command is not available."

I think this means that the COM interface does not support the procedure (command).  But why?  Why does it appear in intellisense and compile?  Is there a workaround?

Comment: What do you try to set BaseStyle to?

Comment: I tried a style name and a style object.  I don't think the problem is the value being assigned.  Its a COM exception because, I think, the function is not defined by the COM object.

Comment: Strange, it looks documented. I'll have a look at it tonight.

Answer (score 3):

This simple example works on my machine (VS 2012, Office 2007)

```
        Application application = new Application {Visible = true};

        string styleName1 = "Heading 1";
        object styleNameObject1 = styleName1;

        string styleName2 = "Heading 2";
        object styleNameObject2 = styleName2;

        var document = application.Documents.Add();
        document.Select();

        application.Selection.set_Style(ref styleNameObject2);
        Style style = (Style)application.Selection.get_Style();
        Style baseStyle = style.get_BaseStyle();
        style.set_BaseStyle(ref styleNameObject1);

        application.Selection.Range.Text = "This is the title";
        application.Quit(false);
```

So the problem probably lies in your setup. The message is rather vague and it says word cannot do stuff, for other examples look at [C# and Word2010 : DeleteAllComments throws "This command is not available."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176423/c-sharp-and-word2010-deleteallcomments-throws-this-command-is-not-available) or [search and replace in Word documents via .NET automation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17369973/search-and-replace-in-word-documents-via-net-automation).

Is the file readonly? Does it happen with other styles or simpler files (such as my example)? Are Macros allowed in Word?

Comment: The file is not read only.  The C# code is succesfullly making a large number of changes to the file's styles.  Chaning fonts, indentts, numbering, bullets etc.  But I cannpt change the styles' base style.  I've tried with several of the user-defined styles (I'm not trying to change "Normal" say).

Comment: @user2735420 - is the example I've provided working? If it is, you're probably doing something "illegal" in word's eyes. Can you describe in more details what's your doing? What style are you changing? What base Style are you trying to set?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

The sample code posted by Vadim was a big help, as it did work, and I slowly slowly converted in to my code and eventually broke it, them moved back and forth until I homed in on the problem.

However, I can't explain what I found!

I was specifying all parameters when I opened the (existing) document with Application.Documents.Open().  It turns out that if I specify false (0) for the isvisible parameter, the code fails.  If I secify true (-1) it works.

Note that in either case I can make 100s of other changes to the document.  For some reason I cannot change the base style if it is invisible.

strange.

Thanks for your help.